# Order of $2$-tosrion of elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+17x$ is not bigger than $2$ unless $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K/\Bbb{Q}$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $E: y^2=x^3+17x$ be an elliptic curve.
Let $E(K)[2]$ be 2-torsion point of $E/K$.

According to LMFDB(https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/18496/n/2),
order of $E(K)[2]$ is bigger than $2$ if only if $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$.

How can I deduce this theoretically ?

My thought: $\{(0,0),∞\}\subset E(K)[2]$ is clear, so I should prove other points cannot be $2$-torsion points of $E(K)$ unless $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$ .

Comment: 19 or 17 ? you have both different values in your title and post.

Comment: Thank you for correction, $17$ is what I intended.

Comment: The points of order $2$ are the points with $y=0$ which correspond to the roots of $x^3+17x$.